# Get the object from HttpResponseMessage and invoke a method using MethodInfo.Invoke()

Tags: c#, json, http

I need to filter out sensitive data when logging API responses.

I think this should be done in the LogRequestAndResponseHandler class.

Here is my code:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // This call is required to ensure that the logging is done against the current website credentials.
        ContextService.SetContextUserCredentials(Global.GlobalData.userCred);

        // let other handlers process the request
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        StreamContent contentStream = result.Content as StreamContent;

        
        // First branch for non-stream content
        if (result.Content != null && (contentStream == null))
        {
        
            // All models will inherit this interface
            var method = typeof(IGDPRSafeCloneable).GetMethod("SafeCloneForLogging");

            var responseBody = method.Invoke(result.Content.GetType(), null); // res == 20

            
            responseBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody.ToString());

            Logger.DisplayDebug(LoggingLevel.Info, "INFO", "RESPONSE BODY: " + responseBody);
        }
```

This obviously doesnt work but I need to change `var responseBody = method.Invoke(result.Content.GetType(), null);`

But I am stuck on how to do this.

Here is what the SafeCloneForLogging method does in my model class:

```
[DataContract]
public class SalesPerson : IGDPRSafeCloneable
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SalesmanId")]
    public int SalesmanId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "CarId")]
    public int CarId{ get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "SalesmanCode")]
    public string SalesmanCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IGDPRSafeCloneable SafeCloneForLogging()
    {
        return new SalesPerson()
        {
            SalesmanId = SalesmanId,
            CarId= CarId,
            SalesmanCode = string.Empty,
            Name = string.Empty,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your `SafeCloneForLogging` method is supposed to do, but I would use a custom JsonConverter and filter out the data during deserialization.

Comment: SafeCloneForLogging removes the sensitive data. But that sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Any resources you recommend looking at David?

Comment: Actually, if you deserialize into a type, you can simply apply the "JsonIgnore" attribute to the properties you want to ignore and it won't be deserialized.  From your question, it doesn't appear that you actually create a clone of any kind that is separate from the actual response, so it is difficult to understand your use case.

Comment: Please see updated question with my model and what the method does

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental crux of your issue is that you are trying to perform type-based operations without a type.  The easiest way to handle this is to pass a type to your SendAsync method that you can deserialize to and then cast to `IGDPRSafeCloneable`.  If castable, call the `SafeCloneForLogging` method and log if not null.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync<T>(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // This call is required to ensure that the logging is done against the current website credentials.
    ContextService.SetContextUserCredentials(Global.GlobalData.userCred);

    // let other handlers process the request
    var result = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    StreamContent contentStream = result.Content as StreamContent;

    // First branch for non-stream content
    if (result.Content != null && (contentStream == null))
    {
        var responseBody = (
            (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            ) as IGDPRSafeCloneable)?.SafeCloneForLogging());
        
        if (responseBody != null)
        {
            Logger.DisplayDebug(LoggingLevel.Info, "INFO", "RESPONSE BODY: " + responseBody);   
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

However, note that there are some obvious disadvantages here.  You have to process the content twice...once to log it, and then once again in the invoker of `SendAsync`.

Depending on your logger, it might be preferable to instead add sanitization at the log site, especially if your logger can handle objects and you serialize the object during logging.